# Interpolate new points between two given points

Tags: r, interpolation

Given two points, how can I interpolate and generate 20 points in between those two points.

E.g., points:

```
x = c(2,8)
y = c(2,19)
```

I tried to fit a linear model and then use that to generate the points, but when the x value is the same, a linear line cannot be fit.

Comment: interpolate two points....you mean a straight line?

Comment: I am curious regarding your comment about linear model... `lm(x~y)` works well.

Comment: Except in the above example. What equation of a line fits a slope of infinity?

Comment: @StanLe Therefore `lm(x ~ y)` instead of `lm(y ~ x)`. Undefined slope becomes a slope of 0.

Comment: @BlueMagister Then same issue arises for horizontal lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is weird, because interpolating two points means...a straight line?

Anyway, here you go:

```
> x2<-seq(x[1],x[2],length.out=20)
> x2
 [1] 2.000000 2.315789 2.631579 2.947368 3.263158 3.578947 3.894737 4.210526 4.526316 4.842105
[11] 5.157895 5.473684 5.789474 6.105263 6.421053 6.736842 7.052632 7.368421 7.684211 8.000000
> y2<-seq(y[1],y[2],length.out=20)
> y2
 [1]  2.000000  2.894737  3.789474  4.684211  5.578947  6.473684  7.368421  8.263158  9.157895
[10] 10.052632 10.947368 11.842105 12.736842 13.631579 14.526316 15.421053 16.315789 17.210526
[19] 18.105263 19.000000
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't think to do the same in the y dimension. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Possibly easier to run `approx(x,y, n=20)`

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
yfrom <- 8
yto <- 19
y <- seq(yfrom, yto, by = ((yto - yfrom)/(20 + 1)))
x <- rep(2, 22)
data.frame(x,y)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the divisor in the  `by` argument be `20 - 1`, rather than `20 + 1` ???